# Enabling server garbage collection in a VSTO Excel document level add-in

Tags: c#, .net, excel, garbage-collection, vsto

Is it possible to enable the server garbage collection in a VSTO document level add-in for Excel?  I'm using VS2010 with a Excel 2010 Workbook project and added an app.config to the project with:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This creates the ExcelWorkbook.dll.config with the setting but checking System.Runtime.GCSettings.IsServerGC at runtime reports false.

When I did the same thing in a console, WPF, or Forms application project, IsServerGC was true and working.  Trying the same thing in VS2015 also produced the same results.

Comment: A DLL cannot have a config file.  When the CLR initializes the AppDomain before it starts executing code, it goes looking for a .config file with the same name as the executable file.  So it needs to be Excel.exe.config and it must be located in the Office directory.  Do keep in mind that you might not be the only add-in that wants to tinker with configuration.

Comment: I just tried the Excel.exe.config in the Office directory but that also doesn't seem to work.